# Повесить функцию на a href

Tags: ajax, javascript

Есть вот такая функция:

```
Comagic.push(['addOfflineRequest', {name: reqName, phone: reqPhone}]);
```

Её нужно повесить на кнопку

```
<a href="#zd" target="" data-label="Рассчитать">Рассчитать</a>
```

Подскажите, как сделать?

Comment: @RattleSneyk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<script>
  var zd = function(){alert(1);}
</script>
<body>  
  <a href="javascript:zd()" target="" data-label="Рассчитать">Рассчитать</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function calculate() {
    Comagic.push(['addOfflineRequest', {name: reqName, phone: reqPhone}]);
  }
</script>

<a href="javascript:;" target="" data-label="Рассчитать" onclick="calculate();return false;">Рассчитать</a>
```

Полезно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick